# Bad Request in AJAX

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am trying to develop a WordPress plugin. I am getting `Bad Request` from below AJAX code.

```
    // On change division 
    $('body').on( 'change', '.division', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:localData.statesurl,
            data:{
                division: $(this).val(),
                action: 'division_to_district_ajax'
            },
            success:function(rss){
                alert(rss);
                $('.district').empty();
                var $opt = '';  
                $.each( JSON.parse(rss), function(key, value) {
                    $opt += '<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>';
                });
                $('.district').append($opt);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(errorThrown); },
            dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json"
        });         
    });
```

Could anyone say why I am getting `Bad Request` ?

Comment: Is there any information in the content of the response to indicate why the request was rejected?  Do you control the server-side code in this case and can you debug to see why the request is being rejected?

Comment: Thanks @David. How to debug this code ? How to see why the request is being rejected?

Comment: You likely need to examine your server-side functionality for that.  From the description it appears that this code is sending a request and receiving a response, as designed.  The server is returning an unexpected response.  From the client you can at least use your browser's debugging tools to observe the full information in both the request and the response (use the network tab in the browser's debugging tools).  There you can confirm that the request contains what you expect, and you can find more details in the response.  From there, the rest is server-side.

Comment: Request url correct?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_division_to_district_ajax', 'division_to_district_ajax_function');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_division_to_district_ajax', 'division_to_district_ajax_function');
function division_to_district_ajax_function(){

    $myArr = array(
        'response' => 'xyz'
    );
    $myJSON = json_encode($myArr); 
    echo $myJSON;
    die();
}



// On change division 
    jQuery('body').on( 'change', '.division', function() {


        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php');?>',
            type: "POST",
            data: {'action': 'division_to_district_ajax', division: jQuery(this).val()},
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function(){
            },
            complete: function(){
            },
            success: function (response) { 

                console.log($response);

            }
        });


    });
```